# How to optimize 2 different views infated in listiview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

i have a listview consist of 2 different views, i'm able to inflate them and use them perfectly. but now i want to optimize the listview.

I'm using

```
@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_COUNT;
    }
```

i have declared 2 different view holders used to inflate the listview, and in getView based on the position i'm inflating the view and displaying.

now i'm creating new viewholder always without checking the convertView object. but i want to reuse the convert view. How to optimize in this scenarios?

Something like this, would make sense to optimize the listview?

```
 if(convertView == null)
                {
                    dividervewholder = new dividerViewholder();
                    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.left_slider_divider_item, parent, false);
                    dividervewholder.dividerItemText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_Leftslider_Account_divider_text);
                    dividervewholder.dividerItemText.setText("Accounts");
                    dividervewholder.dividerItemview = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_Leftslider_Account_divider);
                    convertView.setTag(dividervewholder);
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                            dividervewholder = (dividerViewholder) convertView.getTag();
                            dividervewholder.dividerItemText.setText("Accounts");
                    }
                    catch(Exception ee)
                    {
                        dividervewholder = new dividerViewholder();
                        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.left_slider_divider_item, parent, false);
                        dividervewholder.dividerItemText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_Leftslider_Account_divider_text);
                        dividervewholder.dividerItemText.setText("Accounts");
                        dividervewholder.dividerItemview = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_Leftslider_Account_divider);
                        convertView.setTag(dividervewholder);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: is it really worth the efford to create a private-recycling list to prevent memory allocatons? i have a listview with nearly 3000 items of 2 different viewitem-types and it scrolls fluent although i have no view item recycling and i am using an old android2.2

Comment: i'm asking you, is it worth??. how does it effect???

Comment: i spend about 8 hours to figure out optimizing before aboning it. my viewitems have subitems that are not visible if there is no data for it. the recycled item remembers the invisibility. for me: my non-optimized version is good enough. may be there are others out there who needs the optimisation.